# Failed to build Boost::MPI in CentOS with OpenMPI

Tags: linux, boost, mpi, openmpi

I am trying to setup development environment for MPI programming, and I would like to use Boost::MPI, the latest stable library is boost 1.55 and I have been trying a lost of way just hoping to build the MPI sub-library, but never make it. 
I modify the user-config.jam by adding one line:
using mpi;
and use command like:
./b2 architecture=x86 address-model=64 stage --with-mpi --user-config=user-config.jam --debug-configuration
and got the following output:

```
notice: found boost-build.jam at /home/boost/boost_1_55_0/boost-build.jam
notice: loading Boost.Build from /home/boost/boost_1_55_0/tools/build/v2
notice: Searching '/etc' '/root' '/home/boost/boost_1_55_0/tools/build/v2' '/usr/share/boost-build' '/home/boost/boost_1_55_0/tools/build/v2/kernel' '/home/boost/boost_1_55_0/tools/build/v2/util' '/home/boost/boost_1_55_0/tools/build/v2/build' '/home/boost/boost_1_55_0/tools/build/v2/tools' '/home/boost/boost_1_55_0/tools/build/v2/contrib' '/home/boost/boost_1_55_0/tools/build/v2/.' for site-config configuration file 'site-config.jam'.
notice: Loading site-config configuration file 'site-config.jam' from '/home/boost/boost_1_55_0/tools/build/v2'.
notice: Loading explicitly specified user configuration file:
    /home/boost/boost_1_55_0/user-config.jam
notice: Searching '/home/boost/boost_1_55_0' for user-config configuration file 'user-config.jam'.
notice: Loading user-config configuration file 'user-config.jam' from '/home/boost/boost_1_55_0'.
/home/boost/boost_1_55_0/user-config.jam:74: syntax error at EOF
notice: Searching '.' for project-config configuration file 'project-config.jam'.
notice: Loading project-config configuration file 'project-config.jam' from '.'.
notice: will use 'g++' for gcc, condition <toolset>gcc-4.4.7
notice: using gcc libraries :: <toolset>gcc-4.4.7 :: /usr/bin /usr/lib /usr/lib32 /usr/lib64
notice: using gcc archiver :: <toolset>gcc-4.4.7 :: /usr/bin/ar
notice: using gcc ranlib :: <toolset>gcc-4.4.7 :: /usr/bin/ranlib
warning: toolset gcc initialization: can not find tool windres
warning: initialized from project-config.jam:12
notice: using rc compiler :: <toolset>gcc-4.4.7 :: /usr/bin/as
notice: [python-cfg] Configuring python...
notice: [python-cfg]   user-specified version: "2.6"
notice: [python-cfg]   user-specified cmd-or-prefix: "/usr"
notice: [python-cfg] Checking interpreter command "/usr/bin/python2.6"...
notice: [python-cfg] running command '/usr/bin/python2.6 -c "from sys import *; print('version=%d.%d\nplatform=%s\nprefix=%s\nexec_prefix=%s\nexecutable=%s' % (version_info[0],version_info[1],platform,prefix,exec_prefix,executable))" 2>&1'
notice: [python-cfg] ...requested configuration matched!
notice: [python-cfg] Details of this Python configuration:
notice: [python-cfg]   interpreter command: "/usr/bin/python2.6"
notice: [python-cfg]   include path: "/usr/include/python2.6"
notice: [python-cfg]   library path: "/usr/lib/python2.6/config" "/usr/lib"
link.jam: No such file or directory
notice: [zlib] Using pre-installed library
notice: [zlib] Condition
notice: iostreams: using prebuilt bzip2
warning: skipping optional Message Passing Interface (MPI) library.
note: to enable MPI support, add "using mpi ;" to user-config.jam.
note: to suppress this message, pass "--without-mpi" to bjam.
note: otherwise, you can safely ignore this message.

Component configuration:

    - atomic                   : not building
    - chrono                   : not building
    - context                  : not building
    - coroutine                : not building
    - date_time                : not building
    - exception                : not building
    - filesystem               : not building
    - graph                    : not building
    - graph_parallel           : not building
    - iostreams                : not building
    - locale                   : not building
    - log                      : not building
    - math                     : not building
    - mpi                      : building
    - program_options          : not building
    - python                   : not building
    - random                   : not building
    - regex                    : not building
    - serialization            : not building
    - signals                  : not building
    - system                   : not building
    - test                     : not building
    - thread                   : not building
    - timer                    : not building
    - wave                     : not building

...found 1 target...
```

However, there is no generation of mpi lib in the stage/lib/ folder.
I am so frustrating about this issue, it's just make my so exhausted and kind of stupid by working on it all day without solving the problem. Anyone got any ideal or suggestion

Comment: There's an error message in there: `/home/boost/boost_1_55_0/user-config.jam:74: syntax error at EOF`. So your `config.jam` is malformed.

Comment: Hi, Adam, thanks, I also noticed about that problem. However, I do not know how to fix it, I just add one line to that file using the vi editor.

Comment: Hi, I just figure out the problem. When I add the line"using mpi;", I added no space between the "mpi" and the semi-comma, the right way should be"using mpi ;". Thanks